# What does the set $A=\{x_n: n \in N\}$ mean

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm learning about how the limit points of sets are equal to that of sequences, and I'm just wondering what the set in the Title means and why its limit point is $0$, the set I'm referring to is $A=\{x_n: n \in N\}$ and basically trying to construct a subsequence using the cluster point of the set the subsequence constructed is 0<x_k<1/k and I'd like to know why its bounded from below by 0

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: Consider checking the [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/888233).

Comment: It is a *sequence* of points where $x_k \in (0, \frac 1 k)$ for each $k$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA yes but how were you able to conclude that if I may ask?

Answer (score 0):

We use this notation in mathematics to emphasize that we are interested in the terms of the sequence $x_n$ (regardless of the formula).  So if you see one considers the set of the terms of the sequence $x_n$, he can write the set in many forms, namely

$$\{ x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $$
or
$$\{ x_n\}_{n \geq 1}$$
or

$$A = \{ x_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$$

or

$$A= \{ x_n: n \geq 1\}$$

$A$ here is just a simple you can take any other simple. So when one tells you that this set (means the sequence) has a limit point, say zero for instance which means the sequence is decreasing, it means that he is speaking in general regardless of the form of this sequence. For example, it could be $A= \{ \frac{1}{n}: n \geq 1\}$ or $A= \{ \frac{1}{n^2}: n \geq 1\}$ or infinitely many choices. I think it is clear for you now why the sequence with limit point zero is bounded below...